# Resources$NotFoundException thrown when creating a Fragment in NativeScript on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nativescript

I am attempting to create an Android Fragment in Nativescript with the intent of putting a Mapbox map into it so I can get access to the Fragment lifecycle callbacks.

However, I keep running into this exception that I do not understand:

```
System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xfffffff6
System.err:     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName(ResourcesImpl.java:269)
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:1965)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:1172)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1808)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Googling around for hours has yielded few results.

The documentation is unclear, but it seems that the [Placeholder](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder) tag is the correct tag to use to insert native controls so my guess was that this is what I would use to insert an Android Fragment.

Is this correct?

So, I have a Placeholder tag in my component html:

```html
<ActionBar title="Ng Mapbox Demo" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout class="page" id="page">
  <Placeholder (creatingView)="creatingView($event)" id="mapContainer"></Placeholder>
</StackLayout>
```

As a simple proof of concept component implementation based off a number of snippets, I've come up with:

```js
    public static newInstance() : MapFragment {

      return new MapFragment();

    } 

  creatingView( args : CreateViewEventData ) {

    let fragment = MapFragment.newInstance();

    let fragmentManager = args.context.getSupportFragmentManager();

    let fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 

    fragmentTransaction.replace( fragment.getId(), fragment );

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    args.view = fragment;

  }
```

and in my mapfragment.android.ts file I have:

```js
    public onCreateView( inflater: android.view.LayoutInflater, container: android.view.ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle ) {

      let result = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );

      // just doing this as an experiment to see if I can get it working.

      let nativeView = new android.widget.TextView( this.getActivity() );
      nativeView.setSingleLine(true);
      nativeView.setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
      nativeView.setText("Native");

// If I uncomment this line, the content appears but it takes over the
// entire screen clobbering the actionbar.
// 
//      container.addView( nativeView );

// if I return the nativeView like this I get the exception.

      return nativeView;

    }
```

I figure I'm missing something obvious or maybe have a fundamental misunderstanding of Fragments. I have not been able to find any clear examples of how to do this in NativeScript.

If I call addView() on the container the content appears but it clobbers the actionbar and takes over the whole screen.

If I return the nativeView, I get the exception.

I'm not sure what I'm missing or whether this is a bug.

Is there an example that demonstrates how to do this in Nativescript somewhere?

I am running:

```
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 5.3.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 5.3.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 5.3.1 version and is up to date.
```

Comment: clean project -> `npm cache clear`

Comment: no joy. :( rm -rf platforms node_modules; npm cache clear --force; tns run android ... same result. System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xfffffff6

Comment: Does it works if you remove the placeholder?

Comment: interesting. I am still getting the exception if I remove the placeholder. If I comment out my creatingView() method the exception goes away (but creatingView() is not getting executed ...). Well this gives me something new to investigate. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: very strange, just having 
```
let fragment = MapFragment.newInstance() 
```
in the creatingView() method even if the method is not called is causing the exception to be raised. There is something here I do not understand.

Comment: Placeholder expects an `android.view.View` or it's descendent. Fragment works differently, it can't treated like other views.

Comment: What is the correct way to add a fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEBKAC - Problem exists between keyboard and chair.

Based on the suggestion of seeing if the exception tracks with the presence of the Placeholder tag, I discovered I was mistakenly calling setFragmentClass(MapFragment).

To get the example to work I also added:

```
nativeView.setId( android.view.View.generateViewId() );
```

to onCreateView() and modified creatingView() to:

```
  creatingView( args : CreateViewEventData ) {

    let fragment = new MapFragment();

    let fragmentManager = args.context.getSupportFragmentManager(); 
    let fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    let framelayout = new android.widget.FrameLayout( args.context );
    framelayout.setId(android.view.View.generateViewId());

    fragmentTransaction.add( framelayout.getId(), fragment );

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    args.view = framelayout; 
}
```